# Fetch Content from Div Class using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

```
div class="stars" span title="Money Locker :  Pulsa Gratis average
 rating 3.9" style="width:78%" span div


    $item['stars'] = $article->find('div.stars span', 0)->style;
                $item['stars'] = str_replace("width:", "", $item['stars']);
```

i want it span title= data only

i want this data "Money Locker :  Pulsa Gratis average rating 3.9"

Answer (score 1):

try 2 things:

use the "title" property ... need to be exists like the "style" exists as an attribute of this span tag

```
$title = $article->find('div.stars span', 0)->title;
```

or you can use regex, and take the title content between the qutation mark

```
preg_match("/span title=\"(.+?)\"/", )
```